# Thermal Printing on 3-inch POS printer using React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, printing, escpos

I am facing trouble with print layout and design settings of a receipt using my React Native Code. I have explored printing HTML, converting HTML to PDF and printing the receipt, and printing a png image, as well as what I have been currently exploring, which is ESC/POS commands. I seem to have gotten to the layout design I require, but I am facing issues with the dynamic changes to the item list in each receipt.

Here is a sample of my ESC/POS commands with the item list hard-coded.

```
//#region INVOICE DESIGN
  const invoiceDesign =
    "[L]\n" +
    "[L]" +
    "[C]<font size='big'><u>SALES REPORT</u></font>" +
    "[R]\n" +
    "[L]\n"+
    "[L]<font size='tall'>Customer :</font>\n" +
    "[L]Raymond DUPONT\n" +
    "[L]5 rue des girafes\n" +
    "[L]31547 PERPETES\n" +
    "[L]Tel : +33801201456\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[C]<u><font size='medium'>Item List</font></u>\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[L]<b>BEAUTIFUL SHIRT</b>[R]\t9.99e\n" +
    "[L]  + Size : S\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[L]<b>AWESOME HAT</b>[R]\t24.99e\n" +
    "[L]  + Size : 57/58\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[C]-------------------------------------------------\n" +
    "[R]TOTAL PRICE :[R]\t34.98e\n" +
    "[R]TAX :[R]\t4.23e\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[C]<barcode type='ean13' height='10'>831254784551</barcode>\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[C]<font size='small'>Generated on 15-06-2023 by QuickBill</font>\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[L]\n" +
    "[C]<font size='small'>End of report</font>\n" +
    "[L]\n";
  //#endregion
```

I would like to dynamically set the items.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @K J, thank you for the help. I am attempting to do this printing operation via a thermal printer using react-native-thermal-printer. I was actually able to work it out, albeit with the help of ChatGPT. Please find the solution below. Thank you for helping out! Much love, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address this issue using an array. Please find the solution below:

```
const items = [
  { name: 'BEAUTIFUL SHIRT', price: 9.99, size: 'S' },
  { name: 'AWESOME HAT', price: 24.99, size: '57/58' },
];

let itemList = '';

items.forEach((item) => {
  itemList +=
    `[L]<b>${item.name}</b>[R]\t${item.price}e\n` +
    `[L]  + Size : ${item.size}\n` +
    `[L]\n`;
});

const invoiceDesign =
  "[L]\n" +
  "[L]" +
  "[C]<font size='big'><u>SALES REPORT</u></font>" +
  "[R]\n" +
  "[L]\n"+
  "[L]<font size='tall'>Customer :</font>\n" +
  "[L]Raymond DUPONT\n" +
  "[L]5 rue des girafes\n" +
  "[L]31547 PERPETES\n" +
  "[L]Tel : +33801201456\n" +
  "[L]\n" +
  "[L]\n" +
  "[C]<u><font size='medium'>Item List</font></u>\n" +
  "[L]\n" +
  itemList +
  "[C]-------------------------------------------------\n" +
  "[R]TOTAL PRICE :[R]\t${items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price, 0)}e\n" +
  "[R]TAX :[R]\t4.23e\n" +
  "[L]\n" +
  "[C]<barcode type='ean13' height='10'>831254784551</barcode>\n" +
  "[L]\n" +
  "[C]<font size='small'>Generated on 15-06-2023 by QuickBill</font>\n" +
  "[L]\n" +
  "[L]\n" +
  "[C]<font size='small'>End of report</font>\n" +
  "[L]\n";
```

Comment: what package are they using? I need for know for myself